# Fitting a custom (non-sequential) stateful RNN (GRU) model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, tf.keras

I am facing some problems in training the following GRU model, which has to be stateful and output the hidden state.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf #2.1.0
from tensorflow import keras

BATCH_SIZE = 1
nfeatures = 3
history = 30 # shapes input array
horizon = 5 # shapes output array
nodes = 32

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(1,30,3),name="INPUT")

output, state_h = tf.keras.layers.GRU(nodes,
                                  return_sequences=True,
                                  stateful=True,
                                  return_state=True,
                                  batch_input_shape=(1,history,3), name='GRU1')(input_layer)

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(nodes, activation='tanh', name='GRU2')(output, state_h)

output_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, name='DENSE')(output_layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, [output_dense, state_h])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=2.0),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
```

As I need the model to output the hidden state, I do not use a Sequential model. (I had no problems training a stateful sequential model.)

The features fed to network are of shape `np.shape(x)=(30,3)` and the target `np.shape(y)=(5,)`.

If I call `model.predict(x)`, where x is a numpy array with the shape mentioned above, it throws an error, as expected, because the input shape doesn't match the expected input. Therefore, I reshape the input array to have an input shape of `(1,30,3)` by calling `np.expand_dims(x,axis=0)`. After that, it works fine, i.e. I get an output.

The issues I am facing are when I try to train the model. Calling

`model.fit(x, y,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH)`

throws the same error, about the shape of the data

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (30, 3)

Reshapping the data as I did for the prediction didn't help

`model.fit(np.expand_dims(x,axis=0), np.expand_dims(y,axis=0),epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH)`

> ValueError: The number of samples 1 is not divisible by steps 30. Please change the number of steps to a value that can consume all the samples.

This was a new error, setting the `steps_per_epoch=1` threw a new one

> ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['DENSE', 'GRU1'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[0.5124772 , 0.51047856, 0.509669  , 0.50830126, 0.5070507 ]],
>         dtype=float32)]...

Is the format of my data wrong or is the architecture of my layers missing something? I tried adding a Flatten layer after the input, but it didn't make much sense (in my head) and it didn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that the Number of `Nodes` should be equal to the `Output Shape`. Changing the value of `Nodes` from `32` to `5`, along with other minor changes, will fix the `Error`.

Complete working code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf #2.1.0
from tensorflow import keras

BATCH_SIZE = 1
nfeatures = 3
history = 30 # shapes input array
horizon = 5 # shapes output array
nodes = 5

x = np.ones(shape = (30,3))
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)

y = np.ones(shape = (5,))
y = np.expand_dims(y, axis = 0)

print(x.shape) #(1, 30, 3)

print(y.shape) #(1, 5)

input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(1,30,3),name="INPUT")

output, state_h = tf.keras.layers.GRU(nodes,
                                  return_sequences=True,
                                  stateful=True,
                                  return_state=True,
                                  batch_input_shape=(1,history,3), name='GRU1')(input_layer)

output_layer = tf.keras.layers.GRU(nodes, activation='tanh', name='GRU2')(output, state_h)

output_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, name='DENSE')(output_layer)

model = tf.keras.Model(input_layer, [output_dense, state_h])

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(clipvalue=2.0),
              loss='mse',
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])

STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 1

model.fit(x, y,epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH)
```

Output of the above code is:

```
(1, 30, 3)

(1, 5)

1/1 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 1.8172 - DENSE_loss: 1.1737 - GRU1_loss: 0.6435 - DENSE_mean_absolute_error: 1.0498 - DENSE_mean_squared_error: 1.1737 - GRU1_mean_absolute_error: 0.7157 - GRU1_mean_squared_error: 0.6435
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f698bf8ac50>
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Are you sure your code runs? I tried it as is and I still get the  error `Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['DENSE', 'GRU1'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])]...`

Comment: If I understood correctly, by defining two outputs for the output layer of the network, I should provide two arrays as target when fitting the model, no? So I might need another way to do this. Correct me if I missunderstood something.